# Image inside img-tag not the same size as source

Tags: html, image

All-right..
A couple of minutes ago I was pulling my hair out over this, but I think I narrowed down the problem.

In my html-page I want to use the image from this URL:

https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/d/d2/Mrtallimage.png

Following the URL we see, that the image is `354px x 864px`

However, as seen in the following Fiddle, when referring to the image in an `img`-tag, it is `200px x 488px`

(But the right size, if you download the image, upload to Imgur, and the reference it..)

https://jsfiddle.net/hync8ovs/9/

> So it has to be something server-side at
>   `https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net` that resizes the image, when
>   it's being used as `src` in an `img`-tag, right? Is that even possible? And is it possible to "force" the original size?

I'm pretty sure, I've never come across this problem before..

Thanks!

(Disclaimer: I was only using the image for testing purposes in my web-app, that takes an image-url and analyzes the image. It was acting weird with this image and I was just wondering why.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it has to be something server-side at https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net that resizes the image, when it's being used as src in an img-tag, right? Is that even possible? And is it possible to "force" the original size?

I believe the server at vignette.wikia.nocookie.net checks the `referrer url`, and then sends the smaller image when it is not directly (or perhaps via the same domain) requested.

That's `%{HTTP_REFERER}` doing this.

Read about it at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html

Comment: Hmm, that could very well be it. Interesting. I did not know that was possible. Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only happening within JSFiddle it's likely a compression/resize being done by their service. The reference to the image is no different in any of the other locations. If it were being resized by the vignette.wikia.nocookie.net location when you pull it up in another window it should still be resized to 200 x 488. I don't think it's anything you're doing.

Comment: @DonCarlosll It's not only JSFiddle. It was happening in my own web application, and then I made an JSFiddle to test/demonstrate. But it was my first thought, too.